# Real time chart in Angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase, charts, real-time

In my angular2 application, I fetch data from firebase and display them in chart (ng2-googlechart), Everything works fine, but when data change in firebase ,the chart does not change automatically.
how dynamically update values of the chart.

```
<div class="chart"
     chart
     [data]="data"
     [options]="options"
     [labels]="mylabels"
     [columnTypes]="columnTypes"
     [chartType]="chartType">
</div>
```

item.service.ts

```
getItemById(id){
  this.items=this.af.database.list('items/'+id);
  return this.items;
}
```

item.component.ts

```
getItemById(id){
  this._itemService.getVoteByIdSurvey(id).subscribe(
    (items)=>{
      this.votes=items
    }
  );

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you get the data? do you subscribe to an event? if so do you un-subscribe from the event when the data is returned? are you using `AngularFire`? or `Firebase SDK`?

Comment: I used AngularFire

Comment: Ok and do you subscribe to a method to get the data? do you close the subscription after the data has returned? 

If you can post your method that retrieves data.

Comment: I edit the post, I add the method to retrieves data

Comment: how I can close the subscription after the data has returned ?

Comment: You'll need to create a variable like `let mySubscription: any;` then you can use this like `this.mySubscription =  this._itemService.getVoteByIdSurvey(id).subscribe(
    (items)=>{
      this.votes=items
    }
  );` 

then inside your NgDestroy you'll have to remove the subscription otherwise you'll get memory leaks.  `this.mySubscription = null;`  in regards to your initial issue, can you write `console.log('testing');` just before `return this.items` in your service method.  Then change something in firebase and see if the console log appears.

Comment: @Code Ratchet, thanks

Comment: still not working

Comment: Did you write the console.log as specified in my previous comment? what value did you get?